# What should I convert ? and . to in xml?

Tags: xml

For XML to work, I know that I should convert `&` to `&amp;`. What should I convert `?` and `.` into?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`?` and `.` have no special meaning in XML and do not need to be escaped. However, if you still wish to escape them, `&#x3f;` and `&#x2e;` should escape them, respectively.